# Fazer Aplicação Funcionar Apenas em Rede Local - LocalHost

Tags: java, angularjs

Bom dia a todos.

Pessoal, tenho uma rede em um cliente de 3 computadores. Como lá não tem internet no servidor funciona com o seguinte endereço o cadastro de usuários.

http://localhost:8070/usuarios.html

Se eu clicar em um botão que se chama Listar Todos, neste computador mostra todos os usuários que estão no banco de dados.

A minha escopo no Angular está conforme abaixo e funciona no computador principal que seria um servidor, só que no local do cliente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora surgir a necessidade de se colocar o mesmo aplicativo em outras duas máquinas e fiz o seguinte :

http://192.168.0.142:8070/usuarios.html

A tela do cadastro de usuário é até apresentada, mas por sua vez, quando clico no botão listar todos ele informa que não não conseguiu comunicação com o host destino.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como devo proceder para fazer com que o sistema funcione apenas em rede local sem depender de internet ou alguma endereço ddns exposto ?

Comment: Josemar, edite sua pergunta colando seu código e não um print. Para mais informações, veja [como fazer boas perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

No lugar do localhost:8070 utilize o ip da sua aplicação 192.168.0.142:8070, tanto para acessar na url, quanto nos serviços que estão dentro da sua aplicação.

Caso seus serviços  seja o mesmo de sua aplicação sugiro que utilize apenas "/usuarios" na variável urlDestino.

Comment: Marciano, beleza ? Cara, a sugestão que resolveu o problema foi o caso de se utilizar apenas /usuarios na urlDestino.

Feito isso fiz testes em vários outros computadores e deu certo. Eu não entendi muito o motivo pelo qual não estava funcionando. Tem alguma explicação mais fácil de entender, pois sou novo neste mundo Java e Angular.

Comment: Olá Josemar.

Seguindo sua arquitetura, você tem dois tipo de computadores:
- o **host** (servidor)
- o **cliente**  computadores que acessam o servidor

O Angular é feito em javascript que faz  parte da camada front-end que roda a sua aplicação.

Quando você acessa localhost ele acessa na sua maquina local, por que localhost é um substituto para o ip da sua maquina local, por isso quando sua um dos cliente tenta achar o serviço no localhost, ele não cosegue.